# PHP: List out future dates over a particular period

Tags: php, calendar

I am trying to create a calendar which enables a user to book certain times over a period of six weeks.

Is there an easy way in php to do this - at present I am using a number of loops with the following:

```
$end_of_month=cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $this_month, $this_year);
```

this seems clumsy and requires numerous loops to determine changes in month, year etc.

So far I am stumped as to what other method to use as I am sure there is a simple way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[`DateTime` objects](http://il.php.net/datetime)**, using the `DateTime::add()` in combination with `DateInterval` objects:

```
header("Content-type: text/plain");

$date = new DateTime("2012-01-01");
$one_day = new DateInterval("P1D");
echo $date->format("Y-m-d") . PHP_EOL;
for ($i = 0; $i < 42; $i++) {
    $date->add($one_day);
    echo $date->format("Y-m-d") . PHP_EOL;
}
```

This example would output all the dates in a six-week period from the initial date. But it's very flexible and can do whatever you want it to.

Comment: This works fine on my testing server but seems to fail on my other server - is there any reason why this is happening ? Most of my code for this particular project is procedural...